# Continus Process virtual memory increase

Tags: memory, process, virtual

my application will try to copy file data from one file to another file,so i start 1000 task which will perform this operation then the process virtual memory will increase. My qustion is after the 1000 task is completed and then still i trid to run one task then why virtual memory will incease ?

i used top command to check the process memory usage and even i checked for any memory leak using libumem also.

Please help me to understand why virtual memory will increase.

Adding more data.
When i perform the same operation for multiple times, every time there is no increase in the virtual memory but some times there will be increase in the memory. I am not able to understand the reasin for the increase. Even i checked for memory leak also but no memory leak. and the operation include corba calls.

Answer (score 0):

Each "task", whatever that is, of course needs resources to run. Those resources includes memory, both for system structures and for the data you use as well.

Comment: hi i can't get your point, its better if you explain with one example.

Comment: when all the old task has been completed then os can reuse the virtual memory when i started another task but why there is an increase in the virtual meory again?

Comment: @user1934378 When you run a program on the computer it needs memory. If you run two programs it uses more memory. It's the same here, it sounds like you are starting 1000 threads ("programs") and each thread need memory.

Comment: @user1934378 Another thing to remember is that virtual memory is _virtual_. It doesn't have to correspond to actual physical memory.

Comment: yes i agree with you but after all the threads exits then that time why virtual memory usage will not decrease?

Comment: @user1934378 The OS keeps for the application, in case it needs it again.

Comment: so when it will be released?